# How to config and run java project on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I'm very new with Jenkins. I have tried to run projects on Jenkins but all are fail. I don't know whether the configuration is wrong or something. I have read the instruction on the [jenkins-ci.org](http://jenkins-ci.org/) but I didn't understand anything. Anyone can give me a demo with Java project? By the way, show me the Jenkins configuration. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

First question, do you want to build a Maven project?

If the answer is yes, you can create a new job with this template "Build a maven project".

You just have to configure your SCM tool (Git, SVN, ...) and when you want to pool your code (cron tab).

Next, in the build section, you have to declare your Maven goals (clean install for example) and the pom.xml file location (if the pom.xml file is not in the root folder).

That's all.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I have build project from my Github, project on my computer, it is a Spring framework project, I don't know it is a Maven project or not (because I'm new with Maven), but it has a pom.xml file in the project directory, but all are fail. I think my configuration of Jenkins are wrong. Can you give me some detail in configuration, please?

Comment: You have to install the "Git plugin" for Jenkins.
Next, in your job, in the SCM section, you select the Git option and you paste your GitHub URL in the Repository URL parameter.
Something like: https://github.com/BrunoLavitForgerock/my-project.git
In the build section, please follow my explanations from my 1st answer.